# Conditional expectation for random walks

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

The questions asks to $ E[X_1|S_n]$ where $ S_n = \sum_{[n]} X_i $ with $X_i$ i.i.d. of finite expectation. My attempt was to consider an arbitrary Borel set, pull it back under $ S_n $ to get a set in $\sigma(S_n)$, and then average $X_1$ over that pull back and normalize:

$$ E[X_1|S_n] = E[X_1 1_{S_n^{-1}(B)}]/P[S^{-1}_n(B)]$$

for any Borel set $B$.

However, it just doesn't feel right - it seems just symbol pushing, without giving any intuition to what's happening.

Can anyone explain if this is correct, of if I missing something deep?

Comment: This is not the definition of E[X1|Sn] at all. What is the definition already?

Comment: I am working from the definition that $Z=E[X_1|S_n]$ is $\sigma(S_n)$ measurable random variable such that for all sets $A$ in $\sigma(S_n)$, $\int_A Z dP = \int X_1 dP$. I am trying to write $Z$ in terms of $S_n$.

Comment: Which has little to do with the identity in your post, you would admit. To solve the problem here is a hint: can you compare E[X1|Sn] and E[Xk|Sn] for every other k?

Comment: ah, my understanding was that $E[X_11_{S^{-1}_n[B]}]/P[S_n^{-1}(B)]$ is simply a constant for every set in the sigma algebra generated by $S_n$, but I see your point - it doesn't really answer the question. E[X_i|S_n] should all be the same by symmetry, I don't understand how to use that though. Sorry.

Comment: No E[X11S−1n[B]]/P[S−1n(B)] is E(X1|Sn$\in$B), which is not a constant for every set B in the Borel sigma algebra (not the sigma-algebra generated by Sn). // Right, E(X1|Sn)=E(Xi|Sn) for every i. What happens when you sum this over i?

Comment: That should just sum to S_n, so $E[X_i|S_n] = S_n/n$ ( where both of these things are actually random variables on the underlying sigma algebra).

Comment: Indeed, Sn/n. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The distributions of $(X_1,S_n)$ and $(X_k,S_n)$ coincide hence $E(X_1\mid S_n)=E(X_k\mid S_n)$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ (*this uses the fact that conditional expectations only depend on joint distributions*). Summing these over $k$, one gets $$n\,E(X_1\mid S_n)=\sum_{k=1}^nE(X_k\mid S_n)=E\left(\left.\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right| S_n\right)=\cdots$$