# problem with calculation of conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, random-walk

> Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots , i.i.d, \ \mathbb Z \ $valuable  and integrable random variables. $Z_n:= \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$. Derive $E(Z_n \mid \sigma(Z_k)), k,n \in \mathbb N_0$.

$$E(Z_n \mid \sigma(Z_k))=E(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k))=n \cdot E(Y_1 \mid \sigma(Z_k))$$ by using the given properties. I am not sure how to continue now, should one consider two cases now ($n \le k$ and $n>k$)? Another point I am wondering is that if $Y_1$ is $\sigma (Z_k)$ measurable? But if so I could use the property that $E(X \mid G)=X$ if $X$ is $G$ measerable. 
I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last equation is wrong. Because ofc it matters if $i \le k$ or $i > k$.

For $k\le n$ we have:

$$\begin{align*}E(Z_n \mid \sigma(Z_k))&=E(\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) \\ &=E(\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) + E(\sum_{i=k+1}^n Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) \\ &= Z_k + \sum_{i=k+1}^nE(Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) \\ &= Z_k + (n-k)E[Y_1]\end{align*}$$
Where the last equation holds by the iid property.

For $n\le k$ by a symmetry argument we  get:

$$E(Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) = E(Y_j \mid \sigma (Z_k))$$ for $i,j \le k$ and so 
$$\begin{align*} kE(Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) &= \sum_{i=1}^k E(Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) \\ &= E(Z_k \mid \sigma (Z_k)) = Z_k\end{align*}$$ hence $$E(Y_i \mid \sigma (Z_k)) = \frac{Z_k}{k}$$ so $$E(Z_n \mid \sigma(Z_k)) = \frac{n}{k}Z_k$$ if $n \le k$

Comment: Interestingly you give two contradictory results when $k\geqslant n$ and the OP seems to agree with both...

Comment: in first equation k <= n  should be meant?

Comment: and the Indices in sum have to be changed, am I supposed to edit answers? I am not 100% sure though..

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, ofc it was meant $k\le n$. Additionally removed the first part for the second case :-)

Comment: by a symmetry arguement.. what do you exactly mean? I think this trivial because they are i.i.d. or is it actaully not?

Comment: Check Dids answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039277/conditional-expectation-for-random-walks :-)