# Conditional Expectation of the sum of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am struggling to understand the following computation:

Let $p \in [0,1]$ and $X_1, X_2, ...$ be i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Thus, $P(X_i = 1) = p = 1 - P(X_i = 0)$.
The questions is what $E[X_1|S_n]$ is with $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

It is stated that the answer is $$E[X_1|S_n] = \sum_{k=0}^{n} P(X_1=1|S_n=k) 1_{\{S_n=k\}}$$

However, I don't manage to get their...

The definition we have is for a sigma field $F$ and $A_i \in F$ which are a countable partition of $\Omega$.Then,
$$ E[X|F](\omega)=\sum_{i:P(A_i)>0} \frac{1}{P(A_i)} \cdot E[X \cdot 1_{A_i}] \cdot 1_{A_i}(\omega)$$

My attempted explanation was that the sigma field $F$ is created by the random variable $S_n$. Then, most of the definition would make sense, but

(1) I don't understand why the term $\frac{1}{P(A_i)}$ which in my thought equals $\frac{1}{P(S_n=k)} =? \frac{1}{p^k}$ is gone... and

(2) I don't understand why we sum from $k=0$ since for $k=0$ we would have $P(S_n=0)=0$ if $p=1$?

Thanks a million in advance for your help! :-)

Remark: I know that there is a similar question ([Conditional expectation for random walks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039277/conditional-expectation-for-random-walks)) but this one does not really help me...

Comment: Good Comment! Thanks for pointing it out, I wrote infinity instead of n... Now, the questions ist edited :)

Comment: Can you compute $$\mathbb E[X_1\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{S_n=k\}}] $$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$?

Comment: I would not know how... It would be possible to compute $P(X_1=1|S_n=k)$, but I do also not really know how to get their... I am really confused about how to come from the general definition to the first equation...

Comment: The first formula follows from
$$\frac {\mathbb E(X_1 [S_n = s])} {\mathbb P(S_n = s)} =
\mathbb P(X_1 = 1 \mid S_n = s).$$
Then
$$\mathbb E(X_1 \mid S_n = s) =
\mathbb P(X_1 = 1 \mid S_n = s) =
\frac s n,$$
which is exactly the same as what the linked answer gives.

Comment: Thank you Maxim! I did not see this... 
And since the term $P(S_n = s)$ is no longer in the denominator, we can simple sum from s=0 until s=n?

Comment: You are correct that $p_k = \mathbb P(X_1 = 1 \mid S_n = k)$ in the first sum are undefined for some values of $k$ if $p = 0$ or $p = 1$. But whatever values you assign to those $p_k$, the r.v. $\mathbb E(X_1 \mid S_n)$ will be the same almost surely, because the r.v.'s $p_k [S_n = k]$ take value $0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now i got it :-)